# Use git filter-repo to keep only two directories and move one to the root

Tags: git, git-filter-repo, filter-repo

I have a repository with a lot of projects, and I would like to keep only two components and move one of them to the root.

```
   cmake/
     ...
   src/
     module1/
       contrib/
       src/
       ... (more stuff)
     module2/
       ...
     module3/
       ...
   ci/
     ...
   doc/
     ...
```

The result I want is to keep `cmake`, move `src/module1/*` to the root, remove everything else (`ci/`, `doc/`, `src/module2`, `src/module3`):

```
   cmake/
     ...
   contrib/
   src/
   ... (more stuff)
```

Currently I'm using this awfully slow `git filter-branch` command on the master branch:

```
FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch \
    --index-filter 'git ls-files \
                        | grep -v "^cmake\|^src/module1" \
                        | xargs -I{} git rm -q --cached {};
                    git ls-files -s \
                        | sed "s%src/module1/%%" \
                        | git update-index --index-info;
                    git rm -rq --cached --ignore-unmatch src/module1' \
    --prune-empty -- --all
```

Is there a way to do this faster with `filter-repo`? It is easy to find code examples that do any of the two operations, but I'm not sure if both can be done in one go.

The goal is to keep a sub-repository synchronized with the commits from the main mono-repository, so this will run once a day. The existing solution takes multiple hours to run.

I tried this:

```
git filter-repo --path cmake --path src/module1 --path-rename src/module1:
```

But it fails with error:

```
Parsed 3450 commitsfatal: Empty path component found in input
```

Comment: Another issue with the existing solution is that changes are very hard to test, due to how time intensive and resource intensive it is.

Comment: Why are you doing `ls-files` and complicated `sed` magic? Can't you just do `git mv … … && git rm -rf …`?

Comment: I want a continuous history and have the relevant commits from the main monorepo mirrored on the subrepo that contains only that component. And the subrepo should not carry the entire unrelated git history of commits that don't touch its files.

Comment: @knittl It is an index-filter: this rewrites the index contents without checking out any files. What you suggest is a tree-filter, but that would be a handful of magnitudes slower for a large monorepo.

Comment: @j6t `--index-filter` supports `git rm` – you need to pass `--cached` though. It's even in the examples section of the man page. But I now see that it contains a `ls-files | sed` example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue looking at more examples in various examples posted in other questions.

I almost had the right solution, I just needed an extra slash in the `--path-rename` string

```
git filter-repo --path src/module1 --path cmake --path-rename src/module1/:
```