# How to rebase while skipping a particular commit (non-interactive)?

Tags: git, rebase, git-filter-repo

I want to rebase a bunch of commits onto the master branch of my git remote, and do it in an automated manner without using `git rebase -i`. I want to skip  the first commit of my new work before rebasing the rest onto master.

Is there a solution for this?

More context:

I recently moved a project into a mono-repository, but I want to maintain the original repo as a mirror, so we can keep a repository with the full history (to be able to `git blame` without hitting the migration barrier). See [Use git filter-repo to keep only two directories and move one to the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578476/use-git-filter-repo-to-keep-only-two-directories-and-move-one-to-the-root)

My workflow for doing this is to extract the git history for the subdirectory of the monorepo using `git-filter-repo`, and then I rebase the extracted history onto the main branch of the old github repo.

```
git filter-repo --path subdir_in_monorepo --path-rename subdir_in_monorepo/:
git remote add github <old repo that is maintained as a mirror>
git pull github master --rebase --strategy-option=theirs
```

The problem is that this works well the first time, but on the following time I run it the first commit of the new history conflicts with itself (the same commit previously rebased onto the remote master) and the rebase starts undoing some of the work.  This is possibly caused by the first commit (migration commit) changing some stuff to match the codestyle of the monorepo.